# How do I check object type with isKind(of: ..)?

Tags: ios, swift

I use the `isKind(of:)` method to check if `UIView` is of type `UIImageView` or not.

But the `swift 4` complier gives me an error:

> Expected member name or constructor call after type name

I can't figure out what's wrong with it.

```
func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    for subview: AnyObject in scrollView.subviews {
        if subview.isKind(of: UIImageView) {  //<-Expected member name or constructor call after type name
            return subview as? UIView
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: `subviews` returns `[UIView]`. Your type annotation makes it much worse.

Comment: @vadian yeah. I go to definition , find `open var subviews: [UIView] { get }`. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, although it does its job in checking Objective-C type, `isKind(of:)` should be avoided in favor of simple `as?` or `is` Swift operator. So this code (corrected):

```
func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    for subview in scrollView.subviews {
        if subview.isKind(of: UIImageView.self) { 
            return subview
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

would be equivalent to:

```
func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    for subview in scrollView.subviews {
        if subview is UIImageView {
            return subview
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

**EDIT**

The entire method can easily be replaced with:

```
func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    return scrollView.subviews.first(where: {$0 is UIImageView })
}
```

Comment: It works. But why is `UIImageView.self`? Is this a obj-c way?

Comment: `UIImageView.self` is equivalent of `[UIImageView class]`, which comes from Objective-C, as is the method `isKindOfClass` itself. This is not a native Swift method. It came in Swift from Objective-C to check objects derived from NSObject. The Swift `as` and `is` operators basically do the same job of checking an object's type.

Comment: The nil coalescing operator is redundant, `first` returns `nil` if nothing matches the condition.

Comment: Are you sure that code snippet in the edit (`first(where:)`) is correct? it would checks *only* the first element in the `subviews` array; We assume that it should iterate through it, I think what do you meant is implemented in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46807965/5501940)

Comment: As documentation says, `Returns the first element of the sequence that satisfies the given predicate`.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the `is` operator. And you don't need to cast to `UIView` because `subviews` are `UIView`'s

```
func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    for subview in scrollView.subviews {
        if subview is UIImageView {
            return subview
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```